# Displying nested Json data in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, nested

I'm trying to fetch the nested data of my JSON, but the "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" always show. I already watched tutorials about this problem but seems the error always comes up.

Here's the problem, in this section of code, I want to display the nested data of the ingredients then I don't know if my syntax is wrong about the map, but I watched tutorials, the placing of map is correct.

```
<div>
  {recipes.title}
    <ul>
      {recipes.ingredients.map((sub) => (
      <li>{sub.ingredients}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the overall code

```
//JSON DATA
[
    {
       "uuid":"e80ea521-4d42-48fe-a7a6-ac8952bc0de4",
       "title":"Queso Brat Scramble",
       "description":"A delicious breakfast, fit for a crowd.",
       "images":{
          "full":"/img/queso_brat_scramble.jpg",
          "medium":"/img/queso_brat_scramble--m.jpg",
          "small":"/img/queso_brat_scramble--s.jpg"
       },
       "servings":5,
       "prepTime":10,
       "cookTime":20,
       "postDate":"01/20/2018 05:15:03 PM",
       "editDate":"02/05/2018 11:56:29 PM",
       "ingredients":[
          {
             "uuid":"62798278-2fbc-4c31-98de-b7959c191688",
             "amount":1,
             "measurement":"package (19 oz)",
             "name":"queso brats"
          },
          {
             "uuid":"2df619ea-8472-48f4-9615-3f387a492d22",
             "amount":8,
             "measurement":"tablespoons",
             "name":"canola oil"
          },
       ]
    },
 ]

//React CODE
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import api from "../Api/Recipes";
import DatePosted from "./DatePosted";
import "./ViewRecipe.css";

const ViewRecipe = () => {
  const baseURL = "http://localhost:3001";
  const { id } = useParams();
  const retriveRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await api.get("/recipes/" + id);
    return response.data;
  };

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllRecipes = async () => {
      const allRecipes = await retriveRecipes();
      if (allRecipes) setRecipes(allRecipes);
    };

    getAllRecipes();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [recipes, recipes.images]);

  return (
    <div>
      {recipes && (
        <div className="blog-content">
          <div>
            <DatePosted datePosted={new Date(recipes.postDate)} />
          </div>
          <h2>{recipes.title}</h2>
          <p>{recipes.description}</p>
          <div className="legends">
            <div>
              <span className="badge">
                <i className="fas fa-clock"></i> Cook Time: {recipes.cookTime}{" "}
                mins
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className="badge">
                <i className="fas fa-clock"></i> Preperation Time:{" "}
                {recipes.prepTime} mins
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className="badge">
                <i className="fas fa-utensils"></i> Servings: {recipes.servings}
                mins
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />

          <h5>Images</h5>
          <ul>{recipes.images && <li>{recipes.images.full}</li>}</ul>
          <ul>{recipes.images && <li>{recipes.images.medium}</li>}</ul>
          <ul>{recipes.images && <li>{recipes.images.small}</li>}</ul>
          <h5>Ingredients</h5>
          <div>
            {recipes.title}
            <ul>
              {recipes.ingredients.map((sub) => (
                <li>{sub.ingredients}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewRecipe;
```

Comment: `recipes.ingredients` is `undefined` since `recipes` is an `array` not an `Object`

Comment: Hi, thank you, sir, I would like to ask for help on how to solve this? I'm new in react

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you have is due to how react renders and rerenders states.

```
 const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
```

You're initializing it properly which is good. Now if you put your JSON object in the array you should see that it should render properly. When you are setting your state in setRecipes, you're not referencing your state so it doesn't know what to rerender. So even though your state is different, it's not being rerendered thus you having that error. To fix this, your code should be:

```
setRecipes([...allRecipes]);
```

That code will first bring everything already in the state back which in this case is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `useState` like this

```
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({});
```

As API returning Array, set value like this, then you will get `recipes` object which consists of `ingredients` array

```
 if (allRecipes?.length) setRecipes(allRecipes[0]);
```

Change `JSX` like this

Inside your json data there is no second `ingredients`.

`ingredients` array having only this data

```
 {
   "uuid":"62798278-2fbc-4c31-98de-b7959c191688",
   "amount":1,
   "measurement":"package (19 oz)",
   "name":"queso brats"
  }
```

Code to change inside `JSX`

```
     <div>
        {recipes?.title}
        <ul>
          {recipes?.ingredients?.map((sub) => (
            <li>{sub?.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

If possible have optional chaining for all objects to avoid error, like this

```
{recipes?.servings}
```

If you want, you can change images `JSX` with optional chaining

```
 <h5>Images</h5>
 <ul><li>{recipes?.images?.full}</li></ul>
 <ul><li>{recipes?.images?.medium}</li></ul>
 <ul><li>{recipes?.images?.small}</li></ul>
```